# Transfer android project to other pc

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'll transfer my android project into other pc and that application was already in the playstore. I wanna know if i will copy only the project or i'll include the .jks file.

Comment: You can copy the project to other computer,to upload your apk to playstore you will need .jks file to sign your app.It is advisable to copy both project and .jks file.

Answer (score 1):

you would copy whole of project and in other pc open it,
and when you want publish your app (or get a release) you may use your keystore (.jks) file that is a unique sign for your app ,then you can upload new version of released app in appstore.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Version Control system such as [git](https://git-scm.com) and upload your project to GitHub or Bitbucket. You will need these tools if you want to get serious in development